Proof of the existence of an inductive set from the "apparently weaker" form of the axiom of infinity
In the Wikipedia page of the axiom of infinity, an "apparently weaker" of the axiom is stated. It is said that one can prove the existence of $\omega$ using this form as well together with the axioms of $\mathsf{ZF-Infinity}$. The form is
$$\exists x(\exists y(y\in x)\land\forall y(y\in x\to\exists z(z\in x\land y\subsetneq z))\tag{$\dagger$}.$$
I don't understand how the proof would go exactly. The page is quite shallow in the explanation. Can you give me a more detailed proof of the existence of an inductive set assuming the axiom of infinity in the form $(\dagger)$?

Your question grossly misrepresents the text on that Wikipedia article.

@AsafKaragila then I didn't understand it. Care to explain?

There is a whole paragraph, referring to, and relying on, all of the axioms, not just "using separation", explaining how such proof comes to be.

@AsafKaragila I corrected that part in my question. However, I still don't understand the proof given by Wikipedia. For example, I don't understand exactly how I should go about proving the existence of subsets of any finite cardinality.

How do you define "finite" is my first question. First answer that. Then we can talk about how the set $x$ given by this axiom is not finite, and then ${a\subseteq x\mid a\text{ is finite}}$ is going to either have a maximal element (under $\subseteq$), in which case $x$ will be finite, or else it will have finite sets of all sizes.

@AsafKaragila can it be shown that this form of Infinity implies the "standard form," so that the existence of $\omega$ can be proven in the "usual way?"

Not without essentially proving the existence of $\omega$ already, I don't think.

@AsafKaragila ah, I see. Thank you. Still, there are many things in the proof which are not entirely clear to me. I don't know what the optimal definition of "finite set" is here, but one that does not involve natural numbers (which are not defined yet) may be that a set is finite if and only if there exists no bijection between the set and a proper subset of it (?)

@AsafKaragila also, another question. If I am able to prove the existence of an inductive set, then can I define $\omega=\bigcap{H\mid H\text{ is inductive}}$? Is the set of all inductive sets a set?

@Elvis For the last comment: You can construct the cut even if the class of all inductive sets is proper, by describing it as a restriction of some inductive set $H$. For the second-last comment: Note that the set $x$ described in the axiom has the property, that for every element $y$ in $x$, there's another element $z$ in $x$ that is a strict superset of it (so there's no $\subseteq$-maximal element in $x$). So start with some element $a_1$ of $x$, then use meta-theoretic induction to proof that if $a_i\in x$ is a set, then there also is a set  $a_{i+1}\in x$.

@ConnFus Ok, I guess I understand that. But how would you use replacement exactly? You should do it inductively? Also, is there a way to do all of this without using meta-theoretic induction?
